# Dotnet Core API - Get the URL of a controller method

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I'm developing an API and it has two Controllers: `PicturesController` and `AccountController`. There's a method on `PicturesController` that returns an image and I'd like to know how to get its URL.

On another `PicturesController` method, I got the URL using the code bellow:

```
var url = Url.RouteUrl("GetPicture", new { id = picture.Id }, Request.Scheme);
```

But I need to get the URL of the same method, however from another controller (`AccountController`).

I tried the following code, but it results null.

```
var url = Url.Action("GetPicture", "PicturesController", new { id = picture.Id }, Request.Scheme);
```

That's the method:

```
public class PicturesController : Controller
{
  ...

   // GET api/pictures/id
    [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetPicture")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Get(Guid id)
    {
        var picture = await _context.Pictures.FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.IsActive() && p.Id == id);

        if (picture == null)
            return NotFound();

        return File(picture.PictureImage, "image/jpg");
    }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Your code says `GetPicture` but the action is called `Get`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `GetPicture` in this code:

```
var url = Url.Action("GetPicture", "PicturesController", new { id = picture.Id }, Request.Scheme);
```

The first parameter for [`Url.Action`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.urlhelperextensions.action?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_UrlHelperExtensions_Action_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_IUrlHelper_System_String_System_String_System_Object_System_String_) is the name of the *action*, which in your case is `Get`, so it should be

```
var url = Url.Action("Get", "PicturesController", new { id = picture.Id }, Request.Scheme);
```

Comment: Avoid using literal strings, use nameof(GetPicture) and nameof(PicturesController) instead.