# Get base url to controller using UrlHelper

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm trying to implement some kind of auto discovery feature into my web API using `AspNetCore 3.1`.
What I want to do is to generate some base urls to certain controllers using `UrlHelper`.

Let's suppose I have the following controllers:

```
[Route("api/routeA", Name = nameof(ControllerA))]
public class ControllerA : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public string GetUrlToControllerB()
    {
        return Url.RouteUrl(nameof(ControllerB));
    }
}

[Route("api/routeB", Name = nameof(ControllerB))]
public class ControllerB : ControllerBase
{
}
```

Unfortunately this always returns a `204` because `RouteUrl` returns `null`.
What I expected to see was something like `http://localhost:5000/api/routeB`

Am I just doing something wrong here or is this just not supported?

Comment: does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54505817/dotnet-core-api-get-the-url-of-a-controller-method ?

Comment: @BohdanStupak well not exactly as the post is about urls to specific actions, i need the url to the controller itself, not to a specific action inside a controller. but now i know how to get links to actions so this isn't too bad :) thx

Comment: A controller has no route, so there's no "base URL" for a controller. The actions are the endpoints, and define the route. Every action in a controller could have a totally custom route unlike any of the others in that controller, if you so chose.